# Is there an equivalent of convmtx2() in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

Matlab has a very handy function, convmtx2(), to represent convolution as matrix product.
Is there any equivalent function in Python libraries(Numpy, Scipy, OpenCV)? If not, how can I design such a function?

References:
[CONVMTX2()](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/convmtx2.html)

Comment: Since convmtx2 just creates a Toeplikz matrix, you could implement the same functionality using [`scipy.linalg.toeplitz`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.toeplitz.html#scipy.linalg.toeplitz). An attempt at this is given in this [Github issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7834). It looks like a similar function also ships with the [`pylops` packages](https://pylops.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pylops/utils/signalprocessing.html)